# j2objc error while compile the project x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've been converted the library from Java into Objective-C. But I can't launch the project .
How to fix this issue?

Comment: You have code referencing something in the AppDeledate.m file that is not really there. Post source code.

Comment: One common cause is that the module that contains the missing symbol has not been added to the target.